# How to create dynamic .mdsqx query for Master Data Services Excel Add-On?

Tags: excel, t-sql, master-data-services

Is there a way to modify MDS Excel Add-On saved XML query to work dynamically? 
I'd like to filter results based on other linked entities.

I figured out the hardcoding way to change filter parameters for example `[Group] IN ('1','2','3')` but I can't get `[Group] IN (SELECT Group FROM tbl WHERE x=y)` to work.

Suggestions are highly appreciated!